# Importing and saving data from csv file in yii

Tags: php, csv, yii

This is what my csv file looks like:
[image]

I have three fields (`import site`, `import goods`, `import status`) to import respective data. So if a user clicks on `import site` only sites name will get saved and the rest won't, similarly for `import goods` and `import status`.

[image]

The `site's` data and `status's` data are saved in a single table but the `goods` data is being saved in other table with respect to it's site. How do i save them into multiple tables?

Comment: once you extract the data, use an event handler to save information in parent and child tables? - have to implemented anything on this yet, show us some code

Comment: Here is the link : http://pastebin.com/jxAPVF03 Please let me know what am i doing wrong.(it is only a portion of the code)

Comment: on if (!$modelSiteManagement->save()) {, extract the id of the saved model from the variable and save the other record in the child table if I am assuming what you are trying to do here right.

Comment: @themosquitokiller how do i read the next line in the csv file, i only get the first row of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will share simple snippet to parse csv files, maybe this can help

```
$i=0; $keys=array();$output=array();
        $handle=fopen($filename, "r");
        if ($handle){
             while(($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
                $i++;
                if ($i==1) {
                   $keys=$line;
                }
                elseif ($i>1){ 
                    $attr=array();
                    foreach($line as $k=>$v){
                        $attr[$keys[$k]]=$v;
                    }
                    $output[]=$attr;
                }    
             }
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

This will do the job, i'm using it always when come to csv. To make this work 1st line must contain keys, for example:

```
import_site, import_goods, import_status
```

In your `$output` array you'll have data with keys `$output["import_site"]` and so on.

Hope this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

In case problems with csv generated on mac remember do this:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

can save a lots of time ;)