# Difficulty with import data from Excel

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-excel

Hi I want to import data from Excel and store in database. The following code is working but it importing column name also as records. For example, if the Excel sheet contains **2 columns** column 1 is **Name** and column 2 is **Email** and it contains **two record** if I select browse and click on import it is adding three records to table including its column name also. I want to add only records.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $name = $filesop[0];
        $email = $filesop[1];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO excel(name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
        $c = $c + 1;
    }

        if($sql){
            echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }

}
```

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155461/importing-and-saving-data-from-csv-file-in-yii

Answer (score 2):

The first cycle of the while loop contains those column names. You can simply skip it since you already have a loop counter

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $c = $c + 1;
        if ($c == 1)
              continue;
        $name = $filesop[0];
        $email = $filesop[1];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO excel(name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
    }
```