# For import and export records using csv file ,which one is best to work in yii?

Tags: yii

For importing and exporting records using csv file,give me some suggestion to proceed.
I need to import the csv file with some combo-box values too.Advise me

With Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking but it looks like a tool request. Questions asking us to find or recommend something are off topic. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Am asking for the csv extensions.Which extension in the yii can help my needs?How Can I implement combo box in the csv file to import?
Am using like: 
               $fp = fopen($file->tempName, 'r');
            if($fp)
            {         ...      
                $first_time = true;
             do {
                ....
                }while( ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ";")) != FALSE);
                    } }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155461/importing-and-saving-data-from-csv-file-in-yii/21158534#21158534